# Access form inside ng-include within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-include

I want to create a wizard in my app . I displayed nav steps and by onclicking steps, I am changing contents of `ng-include`. `ng-Include` consist of a form name `stepForm` which I want to access from outside. Inside form I have some fields which are dynamically generating from and I just want to check if the form is `$valid` on each step.

When I return form from inside `ng-include` to a function it is working fine but in some cases I want to test from outside, Suppose I have button here to test the validity of form , how do I achieve that . Need help?

```
    <div ng-controller="StepController">
<div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="endCall()"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i>End Call</button>
    </div>
        <div class="stepwizard">
            <div class="stepwizard-row">
                <div class="stepwizard-step" ng-repeat="step in view.steps">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="goToStep($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">{{step}}</a>
                    <p>Step {{step}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="step in view.steps">
            <div ng-if="$index==getCurrentStep()">
                <div ng-include="view.template">
                   <form name="stepForm" novalidate>
                    some form fields which I am validation and just want to check form is valid or not
                   </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




     $scope.view = {
          steps: ['Step 1', 'Step 2'],
          currentStepNumber: 0,
       }
         $scope.getCurrentStep = function () {
            return $scope.view.currentStepNumber;
        };
        $scope.goToStep = function (index) {
            if (typeof $scope.view.steps[index] != "undefined") {
                $scope.view.currentStepNumber = index;
            }
        };
        $scope.endCall=function(){  form is valid or not ?? }
```

Comment: you may wanna use an existing directive for your wizard like: https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

Comment: No i dont want to use external one .

Comment: What is the specific problem? What does *"test from outside"* mean?

Comment: How to access form which is inside ng-include from controller

Comment: Question edited please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a child scope. My guess is your problem is that the form validation object is in that child scope

Suggest adding a form object in controller and using that form object as `name` of `<form>`

```
$scope.wiz_form ={};
```

In view

```
<form name="wiz_form.step_1" novalidate>
```

Issues like this disappear when you use `controllerAs` methodology

Comment: I tried this approach but when I change step to 2 I got form undefined in this variable

Comment: Create a plunker demo that replicates problem

Comment: Thanks I solved it by make $scope.wiz_form =[]; as an array and inside ng-include I renamed the form by index like wiz_form[{{$index}}] and test validity on endCall button like this $scope.wiz_form[$scope.view.currentStepNumber].$valid